# Domain change 301 redirect individually only some pages and all other pages to another URL

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am moving a domain to another domain. I need to redirect some specific pages of the old domain to some specific pages on new domain with 301 via htaccessm but I also need to redirect all other more generic pages of the old domain  to another set of more generic pages of the new domain. I tried this with no luck:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 

redirect 301 /busca/apartamento/rio http://www.newdomain.com/apartamentos/rio/resultados

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/apartamentos? [R=301,L]
```

This does not work because it redirects all the pages to http://www.newdomain.com/apartamentos and I need to redirect to this url only the pages that do not have a single page redirection rule.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick (I've replaced "newdomain.com" with "example.com"):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit

# directives are processed top-down and halt on match (L)

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^busca\/apartamento\/rio$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/apartamentos\/rio\/resultados\/" [R=301,L]

# Redirect all other pages to http://www.example.com/apartamentos
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/apartamentos\/" [R=301,L]
```

Remove the backslashes if your server does not require special characters to be escaped - my shared host did.